# CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not complete SSL handshake. win2003server

Tags: ubuntu, nagios, nsclient++

win2003k with nsclinet++ (remote host) 0.4.4.19 and ubuntu 16 serv with nagios (monitoring host).

my nsclient.ini

```
[/settings/default]
allowed hosts = 127.0.0.1,::1,10.50.133.98
password = 12345
port=5666
; Undocumented section
[/settings/NRPE/server] 
allow_arguments=1
allowed ciphers=ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH
verify mode = peer-cert
insecure = true
[/modules]
CheckExternalScripts = 1
CheckHelpers = 1
CheckEventLog = 1
CheckNSCP = 1
CheckDisk = 1
CheckSystem = 1
NRPEServer = 1
```

from 10.50.133.198 host i made:

```
check_nrpe -H 10.50.133.100
```

i got:

```
**CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not complete SSL handshake.**
```

also in nagios:

```
missing -l parameters
```

[nagios img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOUGf.png)

several times leloaded service (nagios and nsclient serv)..
what should i do? i read other soulutions but they didnt help me.

Comment: What does the NSClient++ log say? I find "verify mode = peer-cert" dubious as you are using insecure and thus not certificates so enforcing validation of remote certificate wont work...